# How to execute a .Net windows application using BATCH Script

Tags: .net, windows, batch-file

I want to write a batch script to execute the .Net based windows application.I have copied a files from

> bin

folder into a new folder. I clicked the `test.exe` file. Am able to execute the application.The same process i want to run using Batch script.

I tried below lines in my batch script - `test.bat`

```
@echo off 
START d:\test.exe
```

I'm not able to execute the file.

If I tried this  `START Notepad.exe` in the script. I can able to execute notepad.

Please help to create the batch script

Comment: What "new folder" did you place `test.exe` in? You need to use it in your batch file (you don't need `START`):  If you put `test.exe` in the `TestApp` folder on drive `D:`,  then `D:\TestApp\test.exe` in your batch file will work.

Comment: @KenWhite It didn't work for me. I tried exactly what you said.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for redirect me to fix issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in the same direcotry, this will help you spot out the mistake easily.

```
 Pushd D:
 start test.exe
 Popd
 pause
```

This way you can see if there are errors with the path or if there are errors with the execution of the program. Also notice we leave `Echo on` so we can see the error message that comes up. If this doesn't work, then tell me the error message you are getting.

Mona

Comment: If I put in the same folder it works for me. But I would like to run the batch script from the different folder not in the same .exe folder. Can you help me on this.?

Comment: Thank you for redirect me to fix issue

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.

My `test.exe` file located in

> D:\TestFolder

I need to write the Batch file from D:\

Since I have wrote the below code into Batch script

```
@echo off 
cd D:\TestFolder
START test.exe
```

I'm able to execute successfully. Thank you all for help to fix the issue.